# How to escape a colon when parsing XML in actionscript?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

say I have XML like this:

```
<root>
  <x:Item>test</x:Item>
</root>
```

How would I navigate to the `x:Item` node?

I tried `myXml..x:Item` and `myXml..x::Item` but both throw errors.  The first won't compile and the second complains about me trying to use NameSpace '0'.

Comment: That's a namespace. Who stole your namespace declarations?

Comment: @bmargulies, it had to do with namespaces as you suspected.  If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: No need. I don't know actionscript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up adding the namespace to my XML in my actionscript and that solved the issue.  You can find the documentation [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_09.html#123882).  The coded endedup looking like this:

```
var wNS:Namespace = new Namespace("w", "http://www.test.com/weather/");
myXmlMessage.addNamespace(wNS);
```

Comment: +1 for following up and documenting the answer to your own question. Someone else will have the same question and see how to register namespaces in their actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

Just on top of my head...

```
myXML[0].Item
```